# Pass context into a template using Ajax, Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-rest-framework

I have one view that I'm trying to display data from a few different places to.  My thought would be to do this via Ajax since I won't have a way to execute 3 or 4 urls when this page loads.

I'm able to get the data to the page using the Django Rest Framework and I can view the correct data in the console with my ajax request. I just don't know how to get that data into my html template to start displaying it. Normally I would just pass the context through the view but this is uncharted territory.

I think i'm missing something very small with Jquery as I'm pretty new to javascript and Jquery.

**views.py**

```
class LoadLaneHistoricalCarriers(APIView):
    authentication_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()

    def get(self, request, pk):
        load = Load.objects.get(pk=pk)
        load_state = load.shipper.state
        load_equipment_type = load.equipment_type

        historical_loads_in_state = Load.objects.filter(shipper__state=load_state)
        carriers = CarrierCompany.objects.filter(state=load_state)

        historical_carriers = []
        historical_loads = []

        for load in historical_loads_in_state:
            historical_loads.append(load.id)
            historical_carriers.append(load.carrier.name)

        data = {
        'historical_loads': historical_loads,
        'historical_carriers': historical_carriers

        }
        return Response(data)
```

**Template** this is a modal in case it matters.

```
<script>
  var endpoint = '/carrier_notifications/load/historical_carriers/400192/data/'
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: endpoint,
        success: function (data) {
          carriers = data.historical_carriers
          console.log(carriers) //This works
        },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
      });
</script>

<table class="table table-condensed" id="historicalCarriers">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Load Number</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for carrier in carriers %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="#">{{ carrier }}</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you tell me in which template your modal is? does it share the same template with your endpoint?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should return your response as Json Object

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

data = {
    'historical_loads': historical_loads,
    'historical_carriers': historical_carriers

    }
return JsonResponse(data)
```

**jquery** 1st Option (No django for loop needed):

```
var tbody = $("tbody")
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function (data) {
      carriers = data.historical_carriers
      for(var i = 0 ; i < carriers.length ; i++){
          html = '<tr><td><a href="#">'+carriers[i]+'</a></td></tr>';
          tbody.append(html)
      }
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
  });
```

Comment: awesome! This did actually produce what I needed. I need to go through and tweak it to make it better for my use case though. I clearly have some javascript to learn. Is it possible to just pass the data to my template so that I can use a django for loop? There's a lot more data that I want to access.

Comment: I am glad to be of help. Of course, in my example, you have an array of names, but you will probably want to have the links as well, just format a well-formed JSON object for your case. **Learning is key**

Comment: Yep exactly, I was able to format the detail links for each name. I'll work with this and tweak it some more

Comment: I know a way if the modal is in the same template as your endpoint. Basically, if you deal with data in the same templates...

In which template your modal is? does it share the same template with your endpoint?

Comment: I want to do the same thing, except instead of 1 line code, I have an entire HTML document which uses the data recieved in AJAX. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

this is an example:
**views**

```
template = loader.get_template('start_interview.html')
  context = Context({ 'upload_response': 'True'})
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

**ajax**

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<your url to the view that returns appropriate template>",
  data: { name: "Tegito123", location: "New York" }
}).done(function( responseMsg ) {
  $('#notifier').html(responseMsg)
});
```

**In your template**

```
{%if upload_response %}
 ...Your html tags or jquery if inside script block...
{%else%}
 ...Do Stuff if it is false...
{%endif%}
```

**mor about ajax** [here Ajax doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)