# Django: Pass context into a template using Ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I know this questionhas been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990320/pass-context-into-a-template-using-ajax-django).

But the anwser didnt quite fit my need.
In my Django project I want to give context data as a dictionary to my templates.
like in the normal: `return render(request, 'the.html', context)`

I first build my entire Website without any ajax, so it would be quite a lot of work to entirely rewrite with the ajax HTML on succes like:

```
$("#div_to_update").html( -- completely rewrite already written html code to fit the new ajax -- )
```

Is there a way to more easily pass context to django template like?

```
$("#div_to_update").set_context(context_the_server_passed_to_ajax)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out how to do it:

Send a normal Ajax request but make in the JS:

```
success: function (content) {
    $("#div1").html(content)
}
```

and in your view return

```
return render(request, 'the_file_to_render.html', context)
```

like this the complete div1 will be replaced by the rendered part of render which has the context